# Change instruction for apache config for linux into config for windows

Tags: php, apache-2.2, configuration

I was given a tutorial on setting up apache2 and php to work with a java CMS called liferay. the problem is that the instructions were written for linux. Can someone help me change these to work with windows environment?

```
ssh into the server. 

cd /var/www/ 

sudo mkdir directory name 

sudo nano (or vim if you prefer) index.php 

Enter this into the text editor. 

<?php 
         echo "Hello World!"; 
?> 

cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ 

sudo nano (or vim if that's your preference) 000-default 

Make sure the first item on the page looks like this... 

NameVirtualHost *:80 

Make sure the <VirtualHost> directive looks like this... 

<VirtualHost *:80> 

Save and exit the file. 

sudo nano liferay.conf 

Make sure the <VirtualHosts> directive looks like this...
```

```
Add an alias inside the <VirtualHost> tag. 

Alias /apps "/var/www/apps" 

Add a <Directory> directive inside the <VirtualHost> tag. It should look like this... 

<Directory "/apps/">

 Options FollowSymLinks 

      AllowOverride None 
      Order allow,deny 
      Allow from all 
      ProxyPass [http://localhost:80/apps/] 
</Directory> 

Save and exit the file. 

Restart the server 

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

things like the directory site-enabled don't exist, etc. so am having a hard time here.

Thanks a lot!

Jonesy

Comment: Just use whatever file(s) your Apache install uses to configure virtual hosts (this might differ depending on where you got your installer from).

Answer (score 1):

The file you are looking for is httpd.conf, probably in "conf" directory of the apache installation. You can also check httpd-vhost.conf into "conf/extra" directory.

Comment: thanks for replying. I thought that too but when I add the line <VirtualHost *:80> and try to restart apache I get an error